# Proof of identity for XOR definitions

Tags: math, boolean-logic, xor

I'd like to show the tautologies of the various definitions of XOR. There is a proof in wikipedia, which shows that the first and last line are equivalent.

Unfortunately I don't get the first transformation. Can anyboday shed some light on which operations were applied?

p
⊕
q
 =
(
p
∧
¬
q
)
∨
(
¬
p
∧
q
)

=
(
(
p
∧
¬
q
)
∨
¬
p
)
∧
(
(
p
∧
¬
q
)
∨
q
) (!)

=
(
(
p
∨
¬
p
)
∧
(
¬
q
∨
¬
p
)
)
∧
(
(
p
∨
q
)
∧
(
¬
q
∨
q
)
)

=
(
¬
p
∨
¬
q
)
∧
(
p
∨
q
)

=
¬
(
p
∧
q
)
∧
(
p
∨
q
)

Comment: This question isn't really about programming. However it seems to be using A OR (B AND C) = (A OR B)  AND (A OR C)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's distributivity.

Imaging `( p ∧ ¬ q )` is a simple variable `x`

So simple distributivity will be:

```
x ∨ (¬ p ∧ q) = (x ∨ ¬ p) ∧ (x ∨ q)
```

and now set `( p ∧ ¬ q )` for x and you get:

```
(( p ∧ ¬ q ) ∨ ¬ p) ∧ (( p ∧ ¬ q ) ∨ q)
```

just what you want.

Hope that helped

you can find more about on wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: Thank you Steffi.. "Sometimes you cannot see the see forrest because of all the wood". :-P